# Is it good for the mind to be excited?

Tags: meditation

Meditation can bring peace to the mind. And meditation doesn't end after leaving the cushion, so the peace of mind should be brought into daily life.

But I do not always want to feel peaceful, sometimes I seek excitement on purpose. For example, when I watch a movie, I know the characters on the screen are illusions, but I want to be deluded to enjoy the movie. Does this mean that I have strayed from the path of Buddhism?

I'm curious if true Buddhists watch movies, play video games, and listen to rock.

Answer (score 2):

Serious practitioners of Buddhism do not watch movies, play video games & listen to rock. For example, the 7th precept is:

> Nacca-gita-vadita-visukkadassana mala-gandha-vilepana-dharana-mandana-vibhusanathana veramani sikkhapadam samadiyami
>
> I undertake the precept to refrain from dancing, singing, music, going to see entertainments, wearing garlands, using perfumes and beautifying the body with cosmetics.
>
> [The Eight Precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/atthasila.html)

Answer (score 0):

no it is not great for the mind to get excited. it causes the mind to become defiled or tainted like an old drinking glass. of course the glass is not for nothing. so you fill the mind with bubbly beer. when you have beer in the glass the glass is the body. when the glass is empty the glass is the mind. over time, the glass changes in appearance from crystal clear to dull and hazy.

[People like excitement, they love it and enjoy it.](https://suttacentral.net/an4.128/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)